# If shared memory, named pipes, TCP/IP network protocols are all enabled which has priority?

Tags: sql-server, configuration, sql-server-2016, network

If you have all 3 protocols enabled in SQL Server 2016, which protocols are prioritized on the server instance?

[image]

Couldn't find any specific documentation on this and don't really understand how it works that well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If no protocol is specified , the connection will try based on the order. This is specified in the **Enabling a Protocol** section in [Choosing a network protocol](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187892(v=sql.105).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

From the Microsoft documentation:

> [Configure Client Protocols](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181035.aspx)
>   Microsoft SQL Server supports client communication with the TCP/IP network protocol and the named pipes protocol. The shared memory protocol is also available if the client is connecting to an instance of the Database Engine on the same computer.
>
> [Choosing a Network Protocol](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187892(v=sql.105).aspx)
>   To connect to SQL Server Database Engine you must have a network protocol enabled. Microsoft SQL Server can service requests on several protocols at the same time. Clients connect to SQL Server with a single protocol. If the client program does not know which protocol SQL Server is listening on, configure the client to sequentially try multiple protocols. Use SQL Server Configuration Manager to enable, disable, and configure network protocols.